# How to build a list of all branches in a tree?

Tags: haskell, tree, tree-traversal

Have a problem with trees in Haskell. There is a tree:

```
data Tree a b = Leaf a | Branch (b,Tree a b) (b,Tree a b)
    deriving(Eq, Show)

tree = Branch 
         ("A",Branch 
                ("C",Leaf 3)
                ("D",Branch
                      ("G",Leaf 7)
                      ("H",Leaf 6)
                )
          )
          ("B",Branch
                 ("E",Leaf 5)
                 ("F",Leaf 4)
          )
```

I need to define a function, that returns a list of all branches in this tree, the Output is  like this: `[["A", "C"], ["A", "D", "G"],["A","D","H"],["B","E"],["B","F"]]`. What I do is wrong, but have no idea how to fix it:

```
branch:: Tree a b -> [[b]]
branch (Leaf x) = []
branch (Branch (a,right) (b,left)) = ([y] ++ branch left) ++ ([b] ++ branch right)
```

The output I get is `["A","C","D","G","H","B","E","F"]`

Comment: At the moment your `branch` function only returns a list of all nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
branch :: Tree a b -> [[b]]
branch (Leaf _) = [[]]
branch (Branch (a, right) (b, left)) = map (a :) (branch right) 
                                    ++ map (b :) (branch left)
```